# Can we have "Hot Questions" in the Mobile View?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, hot-questions

I find one of the most interesting bits of SE is the "Hot Questions" and often check it 2-3 times a day on my PC and click though to the various sites to see what's happening.

I frequently visit SO on my mobile, usually when I'm bored, just to pass the time of day - whilst waiting for the kettle to boil for example - although I rarely answer because it's hard to know the an exact SO answer just using a mobile, but I read the questions and see if there is anything interesting to learn in 5 minutes.

Can we have the Hot Questions somewhere in the mobile view, so that there is more interesting content that you can **just read** in the mobile view?

**EDIT:**
This is the one I mean:

[image: This one.]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since you are after all sites, there is a solution, it isn't mobile formatted, but it should do for now:

https://stackexchange.com/questions

But, it's already there.
Go to http://stackoverflow.com, and select the 'order by' drop down box. It should look something like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was after the full SE one, not the per site one. Updated question with pictures :)

Comment: @DaveShaw I edited my answer to include a link for that, if you are interested.