# Is it possible to view Hot Network Questions on mobile?

Tags: support, mobile-web, hot-questions

Over the last few weeks, I've been using the Stack Exchange website on my phone when I'm on the train to work, and I've noticed that it doesn't seem like there's any obvious way to view the Hot Network Questions that display along the right-hand side when the website is viewed on a higher-resolution format (e.g. on a desktop computer screen).

Is it possible to view them when you're on mobile by clicking a link somewhere that I've missed?

Comment: Related: [Can we have “Hot Questions” in the Mobile View?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136076/289905).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible ... yet. At least on most sites; you'll have to switch to the full site mode with the link in the footer.

But, with the [new responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232), it will work. This is how Meta Stack Exchange, which is already partially using this new design, looks on Safari on iOS when you scroll all the way down:

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even realize that there was a difference between the full site and the mobile site versions of the same page; I thought it was just responsive website design to begin with! Clicking the "full site" link works, thanks, even if the text is pretty tiny until I zoom in.